# not able to install samba

Tags: apt, package-management, samba, dpkg

I am not able install samba.
When i am try to install samba by this command 'sudo apt-get install samba4' then it's give below error.

```
ERROR: Invalid smb.conf
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: /usr/share/samba/setoption.pl: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"
```

I am using ubuntu tiguin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your current smb.conf smb.conf.bak, then retry installation.

After that, I would recommend to diff the new smb.conf against the smb.conf.bak to keep previous settings.

```
sudo mv /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.bak
```

Comment: I tried this now showing below error

Comment: Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up samba4 (4.0.0~alpha18.dfsg1-4ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: /usr/share/samba/setoption.pl: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)